Django ModuleNotFoundError
Проблема с Django, моделью Post.
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        DRAFT = 'DF', 'Draft'
        PUBLISHED = 'PB', 'Published'
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=Status.choices, default=Status.DRAFT)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publish']
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['-publish']),]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

Воспроизведение ошибки:

Запускаю shell командой: python manage.py shell
Ввожу команды:

>>> from blog.models import Post
>>> Post.Status.choices  # Должен возвращать: [('DF', 'Draft'), ('PB', 'Published')]
>>> Post.Status.labels   # Должен возвращать: ['Draft', 'Published']
>>> Post.Status.values   # Должен возвращать: ['DF', 'PB']
>>> Post.Status.names    # Должен возвращать: ['DRAFT', 'PUBLISHED']

При попытке импортировать Post из blog.models возникает ошибка:
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    from blog.models import Post
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog'

Подскажите, как исправить ошибку?

Проверить структуру проекта. Убедиться, что в конфиге в пременной INSTALLED_APPS  есть конфиг приложения.
